# Add a Radio button in signup form

Tags: php

I have found a signup form complete code at the plus2net website (http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/php_signup.php)

I need to add one more radio button in the above form. Please help me how should i add a radio button and it should also write the data in database.

Tell me where should i add my code in the existing code.

Thanks in advance.

Here's the existing code:

```
<div class="col-md-12 margin-bottom-15">
    <label for="department" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Department</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="department" value="ckgs" checked> CKGS </label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="department" value="cnk"> CNK </label>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you done till now?

Comment: <?=getRadioButtonHTML('value_of_the_button');?> this should work, if not, just code the function on your own or insert vanilla html / php code :-D

Comment: show your html code.also which type of radio button you needed?

Comment: <div class="col-md-12 margin-bottom-15">
     
<label for="department" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Department</label>
      
<div class="col-sm-10">
 <label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="department" value="ckgs" checked> CKGS
 </label>
       
 <label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="department" value="cnk"> CNK
 </label>                   
</div>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

As per your code:

```
<div class="col-md-12 margin-bottom-15">
    <label for="department" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Department</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="department" value="ckgs" checked> CKGS </label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="department" value="cnk"> CNK </label>
        </div>
</div>
```

For the third Radio Button with Value `sty` you just need to add:

```
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="department" value="sty"> STY </label>
                                                                                     ^^^   ^^^
                                                Change the above to whatever value you want for the radio button.
```